# Opportunity was NOT connected to Campaign - how to fix?

Tags: lead-conversion, campaign, campaign-member

I had a lead created on 10/15 and added to a campaign. Then on 11/1, that lead was converted to both a contact, opportunity, and attached to an existing account. When I look at the details for the campaign, the lead is correctly appearing as a contact, and it is accounted for in both the 'converted leads in campaign' and 'contacts in campaign', but it is **not** being accounted for regarding the 'value opportunities in campaign.' There is a number in that field, so some of the other ones are being calculated, but not this one for some reason.

Any idea what I should look into or update to fix this, AFAIK there isn't a way to manually associate a campaign to an opp; other than just the 'normal' workflow.

Thank you!

Comment: You can assign a Campaign to an Opp after its converted, by either adding the Campaign Influence Related List to the Opportunity layout, or by adding the "Primary Campaign" lookup field to the Opportunity Layout. - As far as why the Lead conversion didn't create the association to the campaign - are you sure that the opportunity was created during conversion? The user may have checked the "Do not create opportunity" checkbox during conversion and then manually created an opp later. Manually created opps aren't automatically linked to any campaign by default.

Comment: @MorganMarchese I'm not _positive_ it was created via the normal workflow during the conversion. I assumed as such, being they were a single minute apart. I didn't know about the related list nor the lookup field, is there much of a benefit to one over the other? I'm hoping this isn't something that becomes a habit (assuming he checked that 'do not create' box!)

Comment: 100% of the revenue from the opp is assigned to the PRIMARY Campaign, so thats what you'd want to use to track the revenue. Primary Campaign can either be assigned during lead conversion, or if an opp is generated FROM a Contact, it will pull the Contacts most recent Campaign. It can also be set or changed manually via the lookup.

Campaign Influence is a bit more complex, it interacts w/ Contact Roles and can be used to track ANY campaign that influenced the sale in any way, you can read about it here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_influence_using.htm&type=5

Comment: Also here is a pretty good read on Primary Campaigns / Campaign Influence: https://www.leadmd.com/best-practices/blog/marketing-attribution-salesforce-part-i/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a Campaign to an Opportunity after it's converted by adding the **Primary Campaign** Lookup field to your Opportunity. 100% of the revenue generated by an Opportunity is tied to whatever campaign is listed as the **Primary Campaign**

Primary Campaigns are assigned automatically using the most recent campaign on the lead during lead conversion IF the opportunity was generated during conversion, or using the most recent campaign on the Contact record IF the Opportunity was created from a Contact record. If neither of these instances occur, the Primary Campaign will be empty on newly created Opportunities (unless you create a process, flow, or apex logic to auto-populate it). In these instances, you can assign a campaign to the Opportunity manually using the Lookup field.

---

"Campaign Influence" is a related list that you can also include on your Opportunity page layouts, it allows your reps to add an Opportunity to other campaigns and can be used to track any campaign that had any influence at all on the sale. Campaign influence can be nice to see how many campaigns touched a contact/lead/opp before it closed. It also has some ties into Contact Roles. It's not necessarily what you need for this particular issue, but worth noting - you can read a bit about it here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_influence_original.htm&type=5

There is also "Customizable Campaign Influence" which is a newer version of Campaign Influence that allows you to decide how credit is assigned to each campaign that contributes to bringing in the opportunity, you can read about that here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_influence_customizable.htm&type=5

Also this is a pretty helpful article I've read in the past regarding Campaigns and Influences in general that may be helpful: https://www.leadmd.com/best-practices/blog/marketing-attribution-salesforce-part-i/